# How do I build a Laravel eloquent query for parent entries that have no child entries?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can't believe I've never had to do this and now I'm realizing I don't actually know how to accomplish it. The basic structure is `Parent` `hasMany` `Child)`. I want to periodically query all `Parent` entries that do not have a `Child` entry and delete them.

I would think this starts with `Parent::with('child')->where...->delete()`. But how do I finish this out? Do I need to do this using `DB::raw` instead?

If you want to help me one step further... I have a function in the `Parent` model for `isExpired()`. I really only want to delete the entries where `isExpired()` is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).This will give all the parents which donot have child entries. And delete them.

```
$parents=Parent::doesntHave('child')->get();
foreach($parents as $parent)
{
     $parent->delete();
}
```

The relation in Parent Model:

```
public function child()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Child');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually found the same thing just before you answered and it's working well. It wasn't particularly easy to find though!